# How to create python package with compiled code

Tags: python, build, python-packaging

I have created a python package(.whl) out of my python project in following way:

1. `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`  # create .whl file
2. `python -m pyc_wheel dist/myproject-0.0.0.whl`  # convert the .py files to .pyc

I am using python 3.8. The problem is generated .whl can be installed only in same python version. If it is installed in another python version then I get error `bad magic number: myproject ...`.

So my question is what is the common way to create python3 package where I can bundle the code in compiled format so that user does not get access to the code directly and it can be install in any python3 environment.

Comment: checkout https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: decompiling .pyc to .py is trivial, if you want no one to see your code, then you can create compiled .pyd files (using cython for example), which has slightly better version compatibility (like compiling for 3.8 should work on any 3.8.x), and you just have to cover only 6 versions of python (3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 3.10)